# Creating MongoDB connection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am desperately trying to create a connection with mongoDB with the MEAN stack, using mongoose.
My MongoDB instance (mongod) is running and I can use mongo.exe and tested it by inserting some documents, it worked fine. But I have problems to create a connection to MongoDB with mongoose, and inserting a document with the .save() method does not work either...
I first wanted to try my POST method, created a function and tested it by creating some values in POSTMAN. But no documents were inserted in my MongoDB datbase..

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var morgan = require("morgan");
//var routes = require('./routes');
//var cors = require('cors')

//configure app
app.use(morgan('dev')); //log requests to the console

//configure body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//DATABASE SETUP
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/DNZ'); //connect to uor datbaase

//Handle the connection event
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
console.log("DB connection alive");
});

//DNZ models live here
var FA = require('./models/DNZmodels/FA');

//ROUTES FOR OUR API
//=============================================================================

//create our router
var router = express.Router();

//middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    console.log('Today is:', Date())
    next();
});

//test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:5000/DNZ/)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to DNZ API!' });   
});

//on routes that end in /FA
//----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/FA')

    // create a FA (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/DNZ/FA)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        //console.log(req.body);
        //console.log(req.body.params);
        //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        /*
        var timestamp = req.body.Timestamp;
        var prognostizierterBetriebswert = req.body.PrognostizierterBetriebswert;
        var posFlexPot = req.body.posFlexPot;
        var negFlexPot = req.body.negFlexPot;
        var leistungsuntergrenze = req.body.Leistungsuntergrenze;
        var leistungsobergrenze = req.body.Leistungsobergrenze;
        var posGesEnergie = req.body.posGesEnergie;
        var negGesEnergie = req.body.negGesEnergie;
        var preissignal = req.body.Preissignal;
        var dummy1 = req.body.Dummy1;
        var dummy2 = req.body.Dummy2;
        var dummy3 = req.body.Dummy3;
    */
        var fa = new FA();
        fa.name = req.body.name;
        console.log("Hier erscheint var fa:", fa);
        //console.log(Dummy1);
        //res.send(JSON.stringify(timestamp));

        // create a new instance of the FA model
        /*
        var fa = new FA({
            Timestamp: timestamp,
            Leistungsuntergrenze: leistungsuntergrenze,
            Leistungsobergrenze:leistungsobergrenze,
            PrognostizierterBetriebswert :prognostizierterBetriebswert,
            posFlexPot: posFlexPot,
            negFlexPot:negFlexPot,  
            posGesEnergie: posGesEnergie,
            negGesEnergie: negGesEnergie,
            Preissignal:preissignal,
            Dummy1: dummy1,
            Dummy2: dummy2,
            Dummy3: dummy3          
        })
        */

        //SAVE the new instance
        fa.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400);
                res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("debug");
            res.status(200);
            res.json({ message: 'FA created!' });
        }
        });

    })

    // get all the FAs (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/DNZ/FA)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        FA.find(function(err, fas) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(fas);
        });
    });

//on routes that end in /FA/:FA_id
//----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/FA/:FA_id')

    // get the bear with that id
    .get(function(req, res) {
        FA.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, fa) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(fa);
        });
    })

    // update the bear with this id
    .put(function(req, res) {
        FA.findById(req.params.FA_id, function(err, fa) {

            if (err)
                res.send(fa);

            //bear.name = req.body.name;
            /*
            FA.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'FA updated!' });
            });
            */
        });
    })

    /*
    // delete the bear with this id
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        FA.remove({
            _id: req.params.bear_id
        }, function(err, FA) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });
     */

//REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
app.use('/DNZ', router);

//START THE SERVER
//=============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);


/*
// set static directories
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
app.use(cors());

// Define Routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

//Set up routes
routes.init(app)

//run
app.listen(port);*/
console.log('Server started, Listening on port ',  port);
```

I used the "template" from the Bear tutorial:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4
the problem here is already, that there is no message: "DB connection alive". However, in the bear tutorial (whose code I used here), the DB connection is built and I can insert bear documents in the database. However, here it does not work...

and this is my FA Schema model from FA.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var FASchema = new Schema({
    Timestamp: Date,
    PrognostizierterBetriebswert: Number,
    posFlexPot: Number,
    negFlexPot: Number,
    Leistungsuntergrenze: Number,
    Leistungsobergrenze: Number,
    posGesEnergie: Number,
    negGesEnergie: Number,
    Preissignal: Number,
    Dummy1: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    Dummy2: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    Dummy3: Schema.Types.Mixed
    //same: Dummy: {}

});

//var FASchema = new Schema({name: String});

module.exports = mongoose.model("FA", FASchema, 'FA');

console.log("FA wird ausgeführt!");
```

Anybody got an idea why there is no DB connection created?

Comment: Most tutorials are old. What's your node version. `node --version`? You really should not be issuing `connect()` in that way anymore, but first let us see what version of node you have installed. It should be pretty common for actual deployments to be able to run on v8.x by now.

Comment: try moving `var FA = require('./models/DNZmodels/FA');` before making connection with db

Comment: my node version is 8.11.1. But I think I found it out myself now. In my package.json I had old versions of express 4.0 and mongoose 3.6 there:  {
    "name": "nodejs_backend_server",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.4",
        "express": "~4.8.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
        "request": "^2.83.0",
        "morgan": "~1.9.0"
    }
}
I updated  "express": "~4.x.x", and "mongoose": "~4.x.x", and the db connection now works.

Comment: but I have a new problem: POST /DNZ/FA 200 5.497 ms - 23
(node:19164) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
debug
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: I cannot see any error logs, please paste those

Answer (score 0):

when I test your code , the Error (Can't set headers after they are sent) was thrown. you can delete `res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));` and restart service